# how to Recognize the multi stroke gesture in android

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my code. I want to recognize the multi-stroke gesture in my app but it's not working:

```
gestureOverlayView.addOnGesturePerformedListener(new OnGesturePerformedListener()  
 {      
 @Override 
  public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture)  
   {  
    ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = gestureLib.recognize(gesture);  
      if (predictions.size() > 0)  
        {  
         prediction = predictions.get(0);  

      if (prediction.score > 1.0)  
          {  

            DrawText = prediction.name;  
          Toast.makeText(testone.this, "You Draw" + DrawText,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
          if(DrawText.equalsIgnoreCase("E"))  
               {  
            Toast.makeText(testone.this, "Z", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
            } 
         }  
     } 
   }  
 });
```

but when I go to draw the gesture, it disappears immediately.

This is my xml layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Gesture Test"/>
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Check"
        android:id="@+id/checkit"
        />
     <android.gesture.GestureOverlayView  
        android:id="@+id/GalleryGesture"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
       android:layout_height="0dip"  
       android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"
        android:fadeOffset="1000">
    </android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to recognize the gesture when the user clicks on the Button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"` indicates used to make gestures to recognize multiple strokes.

See following tutorial

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html

Comment: i already do that,but my problem is i want to gesture stay on the screen until user click on the button and when it click on it the recognizing process start and show the result

Comment: i have the problem with this line   **setContentView(gestureOverlayView);**

Answer (score 0):

you need to increase the fadeoffset time maybe 2000 cud b helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
gestureOverlayView.setGestureStrokeType(GestureOverlayView.GESTURE_STROKE_TYPE_MULTIPLE);
```